# aggregate a column in a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "V1    V2
    21140 -2
    21140  0
    21140  2
    21140 -1
     3878  0
     3878  1
     3878  2
   20434  -1
   20434   2
   20434   1", header = TRUE)
```

for getting the mean i used the following command

```
sample.test.final <- df1[,list(V2 = mean(V2)), by = c("V1")]
```

Now i want the following results

condition : if the value of V2 for corresponding V1 is negative select that value or else use the max positive value

```
df2 <-      "V1    V2
            21140  -2
             3878   2
            20434  -1"
```

Comment: What if there is more than one value per group that is less than zero?

Comment: get the least value. I've updated the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `if/else` condition check to summarize the column:

```
df1[, .(V2 = if(all(V2 >= 0)) max(V2) else V2[V2 < 0]), V1]

#      V1 V2
#1: 21140 -2
#2: 21140 -1
#3:  3878  2
#4: 20434 -1
```

<sub>Note this keeps all negative values in `V2` if there's any.</sub>

Comment: What if i want to keep only the least negative value in V2

Comment: You can do `df1[, .(V2 = if(all(V2 >= 0)) max(V2) else min(V2)), V1]`